# Servidor http em c

Tags: c

Gelera gostaria de entender essa linha de código:

código completo: https://dzone.com/articles/web-server-c

```
if (strncmp(request, "GET ", 4) == 0) 
{

   ptr = request + 4;

 }
```

Porque adicionar + 4 ?

Comment: 4 == número de bytes em `"GET "`

Answer (score 0):

O interpretador descobriu um GET seguido de um espaço e "come" esses 4 caracteres do buffer, reposicionando o ponteiro 4 caracteres adiante, para continuar o parse com o que vier a seguir.